# Azure B2C - How to change issuer to the tfp format in a custom flow?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, power-platform

I'm trying to connect my Azure B2C Custom Flow to Microsoft Power Pages, but I'm not getting my issuer url in the correct format. The Power Pages documentation says that it needs to be in the tfp format (https://tenant.b2clogin.com/tfp/client-id/policy-id/v2.0/) but I can't seem to change it from the standard format (https://tenant.b2clogin.com/client-id/v2.0/).

I've been looking around on Stack Overflow, Microsoft Answers, Google, etc. but haven't found anything that changes the issuer url. I've also tried hardcoding it myself into the other format but that doesn't work either.

Is there some configuration that I'm missing?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, it's one of the configuration settings under JwtIssuer. Had to change `IssuanceClaimPattern` to `AuthorityWithTfp`.